# Not able to run tests on webDriverIO with `@wdio/cli:launcher`

Tags: automation, slack, webdriver-io

I am running webDriverIO tests using `npm run wdio` and getting below error-

ERROR @wdio/local-runner: Failed launching test session: Error: Couldn't find plugin "slack" reporter, neither as wdio scoped package "@wdio/slack-reporter" nor as community package "wdio-slack-reporter". Please make sure you have it installed!

I have already removed `slack-reporter` plugin from npm package also tried re-installing all packages.

Answer (score 0):

I think you still have wdio-slack-reporter in services in your wdio.conf.ts.